# React JS - Modify body JSON in HTTP fetch

Tags: javascript

I need to modify the 'modelList' in the method below:

```
fetch(fetchAddress, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.props.modelList)
})
```

The 'modelList' generates the following JSON:

```
{list:[{"property1":"...","property2":"...","property3":"...","property4":"..."},{"property1":"...","property2":"...","property3":"...","property4":"..."}]}
```

But I need to send this to the API instead:

```
[{"property2":"...","property3":"..."},{"property2":"...","property3":"..."}]
```

What's the best way of modifying the array or JSON so I can send what the API expects?

Comment: What is the logic? Just removing the first property?

Comment: Just send the `modelList.list` and `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: Removing the 'list' array name and trimming down the properties in the array, in the example I have removed property1 and property4.

In C# I would use automapper or linq to modify an array like this but I'm not sure what the best approach would be in reactjs / js.

Comment: Note that it isn't a react question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, create an object parser that takes the js model object as a parameter, then return the object that the API expects with no unused or vulnerable properties:

Here's an example:

```js
// lets take an object holiday for example
const holidayDataContract = (model) => {
    return {
        Id: model.id,
        Title: model.title,
        Notes: model.note,
        Date: model.date,
    }
}

// you can then use the above function to get the object that the API expects

const myFormObjects = [{...},{...}]

const objectToSend = myFormObjects.map(k=> holidayDataContract(k))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Ali - this looks a nice clean way of mapping object models. I will use this instead.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the OP wants to remove the first property from each object.

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and then return a new object with [`Object.fromEntires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

> Note that `Object.fromEntries` is "pretty" new, so you can use a simple reducer.

```js
// {list:[{"property1":"...","property2":"...","property3":"...","property4":"..."},{"property1":"...","property2":"...","property3":"...","property4":"..."}]}

const modeList = {
  list: [
    {
      property1: 1,
      property2: 2,
      property3: 3,
      property4: 4
    },
    {
      property1: 1,
      property2: 2,
      property3: 3,
      property4: 4
    }
  ]
};


const modified = modeList.list.map(obj => {
  const [, ...rest] = Object.entries(obj);
  return Object.fromEntries(rest);
});

// [{"property2":"...","property3":"..."},{"property2":"...","property3":"..."}]
console.log(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this line to achieve what I wanted:

```
const modifiedModelList = this.state.modelList.map(({property1, property4, ...item}) => item)
```

This removed property1 and property4 from the array and I can now use the modifedModelList to pass to the API method.

Apologies - this is probably more of a JS question than a ReactJS question.